# Depending on function pick a particular onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, function, triggers, onchange

So I asked this question before and got an answer but still wasn't working, I changed the code around a bit, basically I want to choose an onchange() event depending on the function being run.  So I have the following code but it doesn't do anything, below onchange will fire off a checkVal() function and in this function I want to say that if a certain function runs on the page eg. updatebrand() then run onchange event updatestyle(), I know I'm not doing this right:

```
<SELECT NAME="choicestyle" onChange="checkVal()"; >
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>

<SCRIPT>
function checkVal(){
    var e = document.getElementById("choicestyle");
    e.onchange = function() {
        if (e.value == "updatebrand()") { 
            updatestyle();
        } else if (e.value == "updatenewbrand") {
            updatenewstyle();
        }
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

So I have edited the top code with this code now and it is giving an error, I put $lastRunFunc in each of the 2 functions updateBrand() and set it to 0 and put it in updatenewBrand() and set it to 1, so when an onchange happens it should trigger the updatestyle() and updatenewstyle() functions but I keep getting object expected error?

```
<SELECT NAME="choicestyle" onChange="checkVal();">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>


<?
  echo "checkVal() {\n\n";

  if($lastRunFunc==0) 
  {
  echo "updatestyle();\n";
  }
  if($lastRunFunc==1)
  {
  echo "updatenewstyle();\n";
  }
  echo "}\n\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSJgy/4/)

> **Note:**
>   Its really bad practice to use capitals in HTML and inline javascript. That is why I converted to `addEventListener()` calls.

Comment: Thanks I tried your code.  How would I put this because when the page loads then it should automatically run the function updatebrand() which means that the onchange() should trigger updatestyle().  Once loaded then if a user makes a change then updatenewbrand() should be triggered.

Comment: I think you need to make another attempt at clearly defining your question including what each function you define intends to do. Otherwise, we have to keep stabbing in the dark

Comment: Yeah I'm not doing something correct.  So basically when the page loads, by default UpdateBrand() is run, within this function resides function UpdateStyle().  Now UpdateBrand() has a dropdown menu with 2 options, as soon as the user makes a change by selecting an option, an Onchange triggers the function UpdatenewBrand() and in this function resides UpdatenewStyle().  Now if UpdatenewBrand() is selected I want my other Onchange to select UpdatenewStyle().

Comment: UpdatenewBrand() is basically the same as UpdateBrand() except that within it resides UpdatenewStyle() and NOT updatestyle().  Also worth noting Updatenewstyle and updatestyle functions are dropdowns with options that change with Onchange.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think the best way to achieve this is have a global variable in your javascript that is accessed by each function that is being run. Then based on the global variable you can have checkVal() run accordingly.

```
<script>
    var lastRunFunc = "";
    function updatebrand(){
        lastRunFunc =  "updatebrand";
    }
    function updatebrand2(){
        lastRunFunc = "updatebrand2";
    }
    function checkVal(){
        if(lastRunFunc === "updatebrand"){/*do one thing*/}
        if(lastRunFunc === "updatebrand2"){/*do another thing*/}
    }
</script>
```